# equality test for atomic variables in C and gcc

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic

I have a dummy question about atomic variables using gcc.
My machine supports `__sync_add_and_fetch` function; I use this call in thread A to set `my_variable (int)` .

I want Thread B reading that shared variable to test it against a value e.g. 20.
Is it correct to write the following

```
   if( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap( &my_variable, 20, 20 ) ){
          //..Ok! It is 20 so go ahead!
   }else{
          // wrong: it is not ok.
   }
```

If  am not wrong in gcc the `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` might fail when there is a race in the shared variable, but I don't know what it does return; how does it work with `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`?

Problem is what happens also when at the same time Thread A is changing the value using `__sync_fetch_and_add`? Is it always guaranteed that it will return the value of that sum event when `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` is running concurrently?

Ideally speaking and for my purpose, I would really need a function doing exactly an atomic READ only, nor a Swap. Has C or gcc something like this?

Thanks A lot

AFG

Comment: If you think this code has any usefulness whatsoever, I suspect there are major logic problems in your code...

Answer (score 2):

As far as atomic operations go, they are meant to complete without interruption. If you have multiple atomic operations you expect to run concurrently, there will be a race condition concerning their order, but each will be run to completion. For example, say `__sync_fetch_and_add` was first, it would perform both the fetch and the add before the `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` would perform its compare and swap.

You might also consider looking at other methods of signaling. You may have a race condition between the value being updated in one thread and having the other thread check it for the exact value 20. In other words, it could be updated right passed 20 with the other thread never knowing it.

But if none of this is too important, you could just do all this without any `__sync*` functions since only one thread is writing and the other reading; no need to worry about corrupt data. Also no need to worry about the variable being up to date since you have a separate race condition involving that (value is updated faster than its checked).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used the GCC _sync operations but I would imagine they are the same as the ones in MSVC. I do believe that should work. Atomic instructions are always executed as a single unit to prevent race conditions. Now, this assumes that the variable you are concerned about is not mapped to some physical hardware.